# Is there a way to make the contents of an element fill the available height before expanding width?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a `<div>` with a minimum width and a fixed height. If the contents of the `<div>` gets long, it begins to expand the width to accommodate. However, it will expand the width even if that fixed height leaves plenty of room for more lines of text without making the `<div>` wider.

Is there a way to make the contents try to spill into the available height first before expanding the width of the `<div>`?

```
<div class="container">
  Text
</div>

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.6em;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Going off the assumption that you are not using a front end framework ie: Bootstrap. 
I offer the following solution by adding the max-width attribute.

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.6em;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Correct, there are no frameworks involved. As for the suggestion, this still expands the width until it runs up against `max-width`. What I'm looking for is for it to run up against the current width, then break to a newline and continue, until it fills up the available height. Only after it fills the available height should the width start expanding.